# Convenient way to suppress generation of d.ts files that contain only `export {};`?

Tags: typescript, tsc, .d.ts

In my project I have e.g. index.ts with a bunch of exported functions and I certainly want tsc to generate the d.ts files for ones like that. But I also have e.g. a bunch of examples of using the package in small .ts files that naturally don't export anything. When I run tsc, to my surprise for every one of these it generates a d.ts file that consists just of `export {};`. These files are entirely useless. Is there any convenient way to suppress the generation of these, or do I just have to prune them afterward if I don't want them cluttering up the destination directory?